# Bluetooth Modem Not Working After Certain Time

Tags: bluetooth, modem

I am using a Nokia N72 as modem via bluetooth with my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop. It gets connected without any trouble, but after sometime a network disconnection notification is shown and the connection name disappears from the network manager notification icon. It happens very rapidly. Then i have to stop and restart Network-manager with the command:
'sudo stop network-manager'
and
'sudo start network-manager'.
Is there any way to get rid of this irritating process?